# How to include custom packages in vim-latex suite templates?

Tags: templates, vim, latex

I am trying to write my own template for vim-latex, which would use my own *example.sty* package

```
<+  +>  !comp!  !exe!
%        File: !comp!expand("%:p:t")!comp!
%     Created: !comp!strftime("%a %b %d %I:00 %p %Y ").substitute(strftime('%Z'), '\<\(\w\)\(\w*\)\>\(\W\|$\)', '\1', 'g')!comp!
% Last Change: !comp!strftime("%a %b %d %I:00 %p %Y ").substitute(strftime('%Z'), '\<\(\w\)\(\w*\)\>\(\W\|$\)', '\1', 'g')!comp!
%
\usepackage{example}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
<++>
\end{document}
```

Is there a way for vim to automatically copy the *example.sty* file from the templates folder into the folder where the template is being used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I guess correctly from your example, `!expr!` permits to compute a vim expression. May be you could use `readfile()` (you may need `join()`). Now, I don't know whether vim-latex template engine supports multi-lines expressions -- I'm maintaining a another template engine from the same generation as vim-latex one: mu-template, which support multi-lines expression.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, but it is more of a hack:

```
%!comp!writefile(readfile('pathtofile/example.sty'),'example.sty')!comp!
```

This one-liner copies the file *example.sty* to the directory of the new file, so that seems to work quite nicely.
There is however unwanted behavior, as the command also gives output "0", which is why I have added the % in front (which is also why I call it a hack).

As far as I can see, the !comp! and !exe! commands from vim-latex are not very well documented in the [manual](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/manual.shtml), as templates are not the main goal of that package.
My assumption is that if you want anything more elaborate than the solution above, you should look into a "proper" template package.

p.s. thanks to Luc Hermitte for the hint with readfile()!